# How to get Google Desktop to index searchable pdf's

Tags: pdf, google-desktop-search

I've got a scanner that converts documents to pdfs.  The pdf that gets produced is searchable.   However when google desktop indexes the file it doesn't appear to be indexing any of the contents of the pdf (although it is indexing the content of other pdfs on the computer). I believe Google Desktop only indexes pdfs that are searchable and don't have images.

Have others found a good way around this problem? I'm trying to get my household and office paperless, and I'd like to just scan in documents and rely on Google Desktop to find stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does not support indexing pdfs with scanned images or pdf's with a text layer.  See: http://desktop.google.ca/support/bin/answer.py?answer=90651

Other options are:
x1 (as Christopher mentioned above)

Copernic Desktop (http://www.copernic.com/en/products/desktop-search/home/download.html).  This one seems to have one several awards

Both the above support indexing pdfs.

Answer (score 2):

X1 Desktop Search at [www.x1.com](http://www.x1.com) provides PDF indexing for searchable PDFs without any add-ons.  It also lets you preview and interact with the PDF as you search reducing your reliance on Acrobat.  Much better than Google Desktop